# Launch command docker-compose up has strange behaviour

Tags: docker, command, docker-image

Here the content of the file docker-compose.yml to create an image of database.

```
    version: '2'
    services:
          myerp.db:
          image: postgres:10
```

When I launch the command docker-compose up, I obtain:

```
Pulling myerp.db (postgres:10)...
10: Pulling from library/postgres
802b00ed6f79: Already exists
4e0de21e2180: Already exists
58b06ac4cd84: Already exists
14e76b354b47: Already exists
0f0c9f244b65: Already exists
37117d8abb6d: Already exists
8b541f5d818a: Already exists
7cb4855fcd96: Already exists
5c7fe264586b: Already exists
64568a495c35: Already exists
283257efa745: Already exists
222b134fa51d: Already exists
e9a30e7f2a9f: Already exists
86bffc7855b0: Already exists
Digest: sha256:1d26fae6c056760ed5aa5bb5d65d155848f48046ae8cd95c5b26ea7ceabb37ad
Status: Downloaded newer image for postgres:10
Starting dev_myerp.db_1 ... done
Attaching to dev_myerp.db_1
myerp.db_1  | 2018-09-23 10:27:38.647 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
myerp.db_1  | 2018-09-23 10:27:38.647 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
myerp.db_1  | 2018-09-23 10:27:38.653 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
myerp.db_1  | 2018-09-23 10:27:38.682 UTC [21] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-09-23 10:16:13 UTC
myerp.db_1  | 2018-09-23 10:27:38.708 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

I notice that when I add these lines to docker-compose.yml:

```
ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:9432:5433"
    volumes:
#      - "./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
       - "./init/db/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=db_myerp
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=usr
```

I have always "0.0.0.0" instead of 127.0.0.1.

```
Attaching to dev_myerp.db_1
myerp.db_1  | 2018-09-23 10:27:38.647 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
myerp.db_1  | 2018-09-23 10:27:38.647 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
myerp.db_1  | 2018-09-23 10:27:38.653 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
myerp.db_1  | 2018-09-23 10:27:38.682 UTC [21] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-09-23 10:16:13 UTC
myerp.db_1  | 2018-09-23 10:27:38.708 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Please, Can you explain me why the information added in the file are not taken in consideration ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two separate things happening here.

Inside the container a server process is running, and the `docker-compose` logs are the output of that server process.  **The server process must set up network connections to listen on 0.0.0.0 or it will be unreachable.**  It's minimally aware of the Docker environment and doesn't know about things like the port mappings from the Compose YAML file; it's usually controlled with command-line options or environment variables.  (So the log messages you quote should *always* say "0.0.0.0", or your container won't work.)

Outside the container, Docker routes inbound connections on specified ports to specific containers.  This acts like any other service running on the host: the IP address you give here can be any single address the host has (in which case it will only be reachable via the matching network interface) or the magic "listen everywhere" address 0.0.0.0 (default).

With `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:9432:5432` (remember, the second port number must match the port the server inside the container is using) what you should find is that processes running on the host can reach the container, but processes running on other hosts won't be able to.

Comment: Thank you so much David for your help. You saved my life

Answer (score 0):

Docker documentation is quite good at explaining stuff, especially [this post](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/).

> By default, when you create a container, it does not publish any of its ports to the outside world. To make a port available to services outside of Docker, or to Docker containers which are not connected to the container’s network, use the `--publish` or `-p` flag. This creates a firewall rule which maps a container port to a port on the Docker host.

The same behavior is happening when you use `ports` in your `docker-compose.yml`. Therefore, when you set `127.0.0.1:9432:5433`, it literally says to Docker: "Map TCP port 5433 in the container to port 9432 on the Docker host". And you are wrong assuming the Docker is not taking your settings in consideration.

As you might expect, there is a difference between running container and running things in container. You can set pg to run so that it would listen to `127.0.0.1`. In that case it would reject all incoming connections from everywhere, even other container. Therefore it is listening on `0.0.0.0` or **all interfaces**.

There is a way to let other containers on the same network to be aware of your database, but "hide" it from the outside world. The `expose` directive [clearly says](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#expose):

> Expose ports without publishing them to the host machine - they’ll only be accessible to linked services. Only the internal port can be specified.

Comment: Thank you so much Alex for your help.

Comment: If you found mine (or David's) answer helpful, you should upvote it and accept it, to indicate to the future readers that the answer resolved your problem.